# Spring MDP: too many logs containing 'did not receive a message'

Tags: logging, log4j, spring-jms

I used DefaultMessageListenerContainer to make an MDP pointing to an IBM MQ Queue.

Every second that there is no message, the below is shown in the log/console.

"[DEBUG 2015-04-13 14:38:55,124]  Consumer [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueReceiver@19cc1b] of session [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession@9dd6e2] did not receive a message"

Is there a way to silence it  (not show this log)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the log level for the logging category (class) to something higher than DEBUG? (e.g. INFO).

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  I found a log4j.xml in my classpath.  I added one for the package of the listener, with INFO for the level.  How do I accept this as the answer?  I also am new that I am not yet allowed to 'up vote'.